# How to delete both partitions from grub-rescue screen?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grubrescue

I'll go into deep details so you can understand what's going on exactly.

I've been using Ubuntu and I wanted to experience different distros. On my PC, it wasn't dual-booted, I had only Ubuntu and nothing else. I just had one primary partition which was Ubuntu. There was no exteneded partitions whatsoever. Just to clarify: One partition exist which is primary. I tried to create new primary partition so I could install other distro over Ubuntu partition and Windows 8 to second primary partition that I just created.

At first, it didn't let me create new one which ıs I believe because of all the space was used by the first and only partition. So i deleted it. There was no partitions left. I created 2 new ones. It said changes will apply after reboot. I rebooted and what i got was grub-rescue screen. I actually was expecting Ubuntu to open but as I thought again, it didn't make sense because i deleted it and created 2 new partitions which were empty. (This part is my opinion, I am not sure if it is the reason.)

On grub-rescue screen, I got this this:

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> _
```

I tried everything on the web so please don't type this solution because it doesn't work.

```
grub rescue > ls
(hd0) (hd0, msdos9)
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos9)
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos8)
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos5) # suppose this is linux
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos5)
grub rescue > set root=(hd0,msdos5)
grub rescue > set prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
grub rescue > insmod normal
grub rescue > normal
```

When i type insmod normal it says "error: no such partition".

I don't actually want to rescue Ubuntu as you know, so if i can delete both partitions from grub rescue screen, I believe I can install other distro. When there is no partition, it possibly creates its own partition. Then I try to create second primary partition and again I get the grub rescue error and so on and on. (just kidding)

Extra information : I created partitions to have equal space which are both around 250 gb.

Any help is very very very appreciated. I had been trying to fix it all day long yesterday and I got sick today because of stress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you say is correct - you deleted your only partition and created two new ones - you have left yourself with no operating system. Try installing an OS from scratch.

Comment: I tried to install openSUSE but it failed at 98%. Further suggestions?

Comment: @Haggra Install Ubuntu is the only response you're going to get on the Ask Ubuntu Q&A site...  (To Organic Marble: correct answer: upvoted!)  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

You have deleted your partitions and, perhaps, have created two new ones. There is nothing useful you can do from the GRUB rescue screen, you need to install an operating system.

Deleting partitions deletes all the data stored on those partitions. Including your OS. GRUB's job is to boot an installed OS. In the absence of an operating system, there's nothing that GRUB can do. So, pick an OS, any OS and install it. If you [failed to install openSUSE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604810/how-to-delete-both-partitions-from-grub-rescue-screen#comment845127_604823), you can post a question about that on [UNIX & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com), explaining what you did and how it failed. Alternatively, you can install another distribution or even, if you so desire, Windows. What you can't do is use GRUB to get your Ubuntu back.